# Error: zsh: parse error near `\n' when trying to set up deploy targets in Firebase

Tags: firebase, deployment, command

When I type `firebase target:apply hosting TARGET_NAME <RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER>`, it returns `` zsh: parse error near `\n' ``.

I expected no error to show up, and proceed to the next step deploying the project(`firebase deploy --only hosting`).

Answer (score 0):

The cause is in the bracket <>. When I type without bracket(`firebase target:apply hosting TARGET_NAME RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER`), it works like a charm.